# Two concepts about abstract classes that have confused me

Tags: java, abstract

I'm confused because I found two concepts in my book which I think are incorrect. Help me please to clarify these two points.

1. As soon as a class has one or more abstract methods, this class is abstract, even if it is not declared abstract (although it is highly recommended to do so). This is correct:

   ```
   class A
   { 
      public abstract void f() ; // OK
      .....
   }
   ```

   Nevertheless, A is considered abstract and an expression such as new A(...)
   will be rejected.
2. An abstract method must be declared public, which is logical since its purpose is to be redefined in a subclass.

The first point give me an error and the second is not necessary. Am I on the right path?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asked in French, and this is an English-only site (I think).

Comment: Second definition is wrong too.

Comment: The second point is wrong too - it's saying that abstract methods must be declared public: They can be declared anything except `private`

Comment: Both are false sentences. Are they exercises?

Comment: The original translation and formatting edits were sufficient; please chill out with the rewording edits for now.

Comment: This is why questions submitted in !English are problematic, @Jason.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta No; fge's translation edit was fine, and the problem was solved. I am reinserting the opening paragraph as it provides context. English needs to be understandable, not necessarily formal or perfect.

Comment: It was my translation, @Jason, and yes, I am going to edit it. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help can anyone suggest me a good book for java in english ? or in french if possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrong. You cannot declare `abstract` methods in non `abstract` classes.
2. Wrong. You can have `protected` or package-local `abstract` methods as well.

There is one special rule about interfaces: methods in interfaces are *always* `public abstract`. It is redundant to specify any of these modifiers when defining an interface:

```
public interface Foo
{
    /* public abstract is implied here */ void bar();
}
```

Comment: i'm confused because the book is one of the famous books in Eyrolles edition, the writer is CLAUDE DELANNOY, should i continue to read it or stop ? i read about 228 pages ?

Comment: I know Mr Delannoy, I even have one or two of his books lying around (I am French too), but this book is definitely a turd (in French, "une merde"). Ditch it!

Comment: Ou alors ce sont des exercices où il est demandé si c'est vrai ou faux?

Comment: Thanks, i think i will search good book in english, can you suggest me good one?

Comment: They are two rules of abstract class written inside the book.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode Have you looked at the [official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)? They are written well, and are very good. They also include examples. Edit: The tutorial on [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

The book is totally wrong. I would recommend recycling it.

1. A class containing `abstract` methods *must* be declared `abstract`
2. An abstract method does *not* need to be declared `public` - it can be anything *except* `private`